# How do i filter an array inside of a array of objects using filter?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of products and models that I'm using 'filter'

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {

  $scope.products = [{
      'id': 1,
      'category': 'Tv',
      'models': [{
          'modelno': 12,
          'modelname': 'ASF456'

        },
        {
          'modelno': 13,
          'modelname': 'Aip456'

        }
      ]
    },

    {
      'id': 2,
      'category': 'Mobile',
      'models': [{
          'modelno': 21,
          'modelname': 'FGH74'

        },
        {
          'modelno': 22,
          'modelname': 'UIO06'

        }
      ]

    }

  ];

  $scope.search = '';
  $scope.filterData = function() {
    return $scope.products.filter(function(item) {

      return (item.id.toString().indexOf($scope.search) > -1

        ||
        (item.category.toLowerCase().indexOf($scope.search)) > -1)



    });

  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <input type="text" ng-model="search">
  <h1 ng-repeat="x in filterData() | filter :search">{{x.id}} {{x.category}}</h1>
</body>
```

to filter these products by id and category. 
The filter is working but i want to add one more field inside filter modelname .

How do I set the filter to only apply to the id,category and modelname field of my array rather than every field?

How do I set the filter to only apply to the id,category and modelname field of my array rather than every field?

i want to filter by id category ,modelname

now these two fields id ,category filter is done  but i want to add modelname also but modelname is inside models array here i am facing problem

Comment: What's wrong with extending your current approach?

Comment: nothing wrong i want to filter one more field 'modelname' i dont know how to add this @charlietfl

Comment: Did you try just adding another `||`?

Comment: we can't do like that bcoz again models is array @charlietfl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add another or condition like this

```
 || (item.models !== null && item.models.length > 0 && item.models.filter(e => {return e.modelname.search($scope.search) > 0 }).length > -1)
```

Comment: can you run my code based on user enter value we need to filter

Comment: @komal I don't understand what do you want

Comment: based on user enter value  want to filter by id, category ,modelname
now these two fields id ,category filter is done but i want to add modelname also but modelname is inside models array here i am facing problem

Comment: @komal can you test now?

Comment: @komal  tried now on plunker and it works. I replaced it with -1

Answer (score 0):

Do i understood correctly - you want to filter your `$scope.products` by means of `id` ? if so try like this:

```
<input ng-model="id " type="number" min="0"/>
<br />
<div ng-repeat="x in products | IDFiletr:id">
  {{x.category}}
  <br />
</div>
```

JS:

```
app.filter('IDFiletr',function(){
    return function(data, id) {
        if (!id) return data;
        var ids = [];
        angular.forEach(data, function(item){
            if(item.id === id) {
                ids.push(item);
            }
        });
        return ids;
    };
});
```

plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/q9DsvZP4scA1oKsJj3Vu?p=preview